Very slow recursive type
I use an object to hold all of the state in an app. This object is arbitrarily deeply nested and so I want to be able to describe a path to select only a part of this state.
I have written a recursive type which is covering all my needs:

It allows to describe any path through an object from the top (root) node down to every child property in the object as a string array
It allows to stop at any level
It doesn't allow to select sibling or ancestor nodes, only children
If a property of the object holds an array, it allows to select an array entry either via a predicate function or a numeric index

This works but when playing around with a quite simple state interface, the recursion already made it super slow.
So I decided to limit the depth of the typing support to only some levels, after that it would fall back to an "any" type:
// Helpers for limiting levels
type Digit = 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 | 11 | 12 | 13 | 14 | 15;
type NextDigit = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 'STOP'];
type Increment<Depth> = Depth extends Digit ? NextDigit[Depth] : 'STOP';

export type PredicateFunction<ArrayType> = (array: ArrayType, index?: number) => boolean;
export type IndexOrPredicateFunction<Type> = number | PredicateFunction<Type>;
export type StatePathKey = IndexOrPredicateFunction<any> | string;

// The type for the path
export type StatePath<Obj, Path extends (string | IndexOrPredicateFunction<any>)[] = [], Depth = 0> = Obj extends object ?
    (Path |
    // Check if depth > max allowed
    (Depth extends string ?
            // ...if yes, don't typecheck deeper levels and allow everything (for performance reasons)
            [...Path, ...any[]] :
            // ...otherwise check if object is array
            (Obj extends readonly any[] ?
                // ...when array only allow index or PredicateFunction
                StatePath<Obj[number], [...Path, IndexOrPredicateFunction<Obj[number]>], Increment<Depth>>
                // ...when object generate type of all possible keys
                : { [Key in string & keyof Obj]: StatePath<Obj[Key], [...Path, Key], Increment<Depth>> }[string & keyof Obj])))
    : Path;



// Sample State:
export interface State {
    app: {
        testEntry: string;
        testArray: {
            firstname: string,
            lastname: string,
            address?: {
                zip: number;
                street: string;
                doorNumbers: {
                    number: number;
                    appendixes: number[];
                }[]
            }
        }[];
    }
}

// Samples for valid paths (StatePath<State>):
['app', 'testEntry']
['app', 'testArray']
['app', 'testArray', 1, 'firstname']
['app', 'testArray', 5, 'address', 'doorNumbers', doorNumber => doorNumber.number === 1, 'appendixes']
...


This is working "okay" with the small state interface (though I already had long compile times), but is way too slow with a real life state interface.
Any idea how I could change this type to achieve the same with better performance?
Recursion without limits would be the optimum, but it would be acceptable to take out the recursion and manually loops for e.g. 10 levels and fall back to "any" for longer arrays.

Please [edit] to provide a [mre] with all necessary declarations (PredicateFunction, for example) and use cases we can test with. Right now you're just describing a problem but not showing it to us.

@jcalz I added the PredicateFunction type and also a sample interface & sample valid paths

Does it demonstrate the performance issue you're seeing? I'm just trying to understand how we can test anything we suggest.

Most likely. I increased the maximal nesting level to 15 that should definitly give you a performance hit but I guess it depends on your machine.

It is per se interesting that increasing the depth of the recursion has impact on typescript performance with the same interface that doesn't exhaust that limit.

So, it's hard to be sure, but my guess here is that your depth limiting is using distributive conditional types unnecessarily, which causes TS to work more. If we can assume that your depth is never a union, then you can change it to something like this and get better behavior. (Note that Object isn't a great name for a type parameter, as you're shadowing an existing type)

@jcalz thanks that improved it a bit, but it's still not performant enough for real usage

I don’t see a problem with performance in the playground so I don’t know how to proceed. Without a [mre] that clearly demonstrates the issue all I can do is make guesses. Do you have some way of showing others the problem?

E.g. increase the level by one (to 16) and try to hand it over as parameter to a constructor and it already breaks: see here Type instantiation is excessively deep and possibly infinite.
So this is reproducible. When I reduce the nesting level I can compile it but it get's incredibly slow when using in a larger context, that's somehting I cannot really provide in a playground.

It would be perfectly fine if there is a way to write that type with a max of e.g. 8 levels without recursion. I'm fiddling around with approaches like that, but I cannot make them work: playground

Yeah, if you put a deeply nested type and leave it generic like that, you'll see issues. My guess is your type needs to have a way to bail out if it hits an unspecified generic. Something like object extends O as shown in this playground link. Does that work now? Or are we still having trouble?

Now I can compile, but something is not working, see here at the last lines: playground
In the playground I get suggestions for keys that are on the same nesting level but in different branches of the object. In my IDE I don't get autocompletion anymore and not even error messages for wrong keys.

But isn't that a problem with your type as is? When you tried to unroll it manually to a fixed level of depth you had that problem. I'd think the onus is on you to make your type compute what you want it to compute and then we can work on performance. Or, this question is about performance alone, and I can make those suggestions to fix the performance problem, and then the computation problem could be a separate question.

@jcalz thanks you are right, when I remove the nesting limitation performance issues are gone. So the miraculous object extends Object condition seems to have fixed that. If you want to write that up as an answer I will mark it as fixed - and please let me know how I can buy you a coffee!
For the computing problem I will make a separate question.

Please do me a favor and [edit] your class constructor example and anything else relevant into the question, so the question doesn't depend on comments existing forever

@jcalz I renamed the Object generic to Obj (although I don't consider that shadowing since it's a generic and never interferes with the Object type - but always open for a lesson :-)) - what else do you mean?

What do you mean it "never interferes"? Shadowing means that inside your type, the type named Object is a local thing which masks the global type named Object. Inside your type Object extends string ? true : false means something completely different from outside your type. I'm not saying it destroys the universe or anything, it's just potentially confusing for readers because you're shadowing the name.

Thought about it a second time and you are right, it can mask the global Object type and is shadowing. Changed it in my codebase as well  - thanks :)

When you have a generic type implemented as a deeply nested recursive conditional type, you should take care to deal with what happens for arbitrary/unexpected type arguments, and try to make sure that there's no input that will either fail to hit your base case, or cause a combinatorial explosion of computation.  Where applicable, try inputs like {}, object, unknown, null, undefined, and unions of types.

Even if you never plan on passing such type arguments to your type, TypeScript might compute those types itself while it tries to compute constraints for things that use your type.
In your case, if you have StatePath<Obj> where Obj is generic, you can expect TypeScript might decide to substitute Obj with its constraint, which is (implicitly) unknown. So if StatePath<unknown> never reaches the base case of your recursion, then you can expect terrible compile times.
I'd say that in your case you are checking if Obj extends object, but if Obj is itself object or unknown it looks like TypeScript spends a lot of time recursing down. Let's nip that in the bud by adding a way to bail out if Obj is wide:
type StatePath<Obj, Path extends (string | IndexOrPredicateFunction<any>)[] = [], Depth = 0> =
    object extends Obj ? Path : ( ⋯ )

where ⋯ is your original definition.

Another problem is what happens when an input is a big union of things. If you're using any distributive conditional types then TypeScript will evaluate the conditional type once per union member. If this recurses you can end up with a big explosion of types, even if the unions aren't that large to start with.
For example, your Depth type parameter might be specified as a union of things like Digit. Do you care about supporting the bizarre case where the depth is 0 | 4 | 10?  Probably not. Ideally you'd want to just bail out at that point also. So you can move away from the distributive conditional type Depth extends string ? ⋯ : ⋯ and use the non-distributive version [Depth] extends [string] ? ⋯ : ⋯.
Anywhere you use distributive conditional types in a deeply recursive type, you should do so because you really want to process unions. Otherwise you're just making more work for the compiler.
So now you have something like
type StatePath<Obj, Path extends (string | IndexOrPredicateFunction<any>)[] = [], Depth = 0> =
    object extends Obj ? Path : (
        Obj extends object ? (Path |
            ([Depth] extends [string] ? ⋯ : (⋯))
        ) : Path
    );


This should speed up computation quite a bit. There of course could be other edge cases, so you'll need to do lots of testing and handle any remaining problems.
Playground link to code

Thanks! Problems very well spotted and explained.
